# Calculate target orientation

Tags: transform, robotic-arm, computer-vision, robot, rotation

I have the following setup:

[image]

I want to move the "Drill" frame to "Target1" with the opposite Z axis direction. I have calculated translation between "Target1" and "Robot_base". How could I calculate the rotation I need to complete that movement?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've said here, the goal pose relative to the `robot_base` frame has the following properties:

- Takes the transform of the `drill` and adds the transform up to `target_1`
- Takes the rotation of `target_1` and then applies some other rotation to it

It's not clear exactly what that rotation is (you haven't said), so I'll just assume that since it's a drill you want it pointing straight down. If this is the case, your goal is to apply a rotation to the target orientation. We can apply rotations to transforms and/or quaternions by multiplying them (see [this similar question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/25193/how-to-approach-a-target-pose-via-the-xy-surface-normal/25203#25203)).

From that question, assuming your rotations are held in some standard Quaternion implementation (such as tf2):

```
tf2::Quaternion rotation, approachOrientation;
rotation.setRPY(0, M_PI, 0) // assuming we want to flip around pitch by 180 degrees

approachOrientation = targetOrientation * rotation;
approachOrientation.normalize();
```

See the [related question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/25193/how-to-approach-a-target-pose-via-the-xy-surface-normal/25203#25203) for more detail.